# /etc/network/interfaces configuration for urg node

Tags: wifi, urg-node, hector, network, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys. I got problem with the network when im using urg_node for Hokuyo Laser Scan.

After running roscore, I start up urg_node with:

```
rosrun urg_node urg_node _ip_address:="192.168.0.10"
```

However im getting an error that states:

```
[ERROR] [1434516842.963885543]: Error connecting to Hokuyo: Could not open network Hokuyo:
192.168.0.10:10940
could not open ethernet port.
```

I looked this up at Google and many of them said to configure the IP address to 192.168.0.15.

So I edit /etc/network/interfaces with:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

and replace the text with:

```
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
address 192.168.0.15
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I tested the urg_node already and it's running.

However, another problem came up. I could not connect to internet. My wifi speed stucked at 1mb/s (using ubuntu now).

I came out with another solution by editing the interfaces file to:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
address 192.168.0.15
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

In this case, I can change to use eth0 (able to connect to WIFI but cannot run urg_node) and eth0:0 (cannot connect to WIFI but able to run urg_node) by using this two command:

`sudo ifup eth0:0`                 (Set eth0:0)

`sudo ifdown eth0:0`             (Return back to eth0)

I was wondering whether there is a way I can combine these two function together, that is able to connect to WIFI and run urg_node.

Thanks for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211508//etc/network/interfaces-configuration-for-urg-node/) by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2015-06-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/26404/sq/) on 2016-03-29**:
Hi i have the exact same issue here. I tried your method but it did not help. I'm using a UST 20LX. Any help? Thanks! :)

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2016-03-29**:
Hi there! Its been quite some time back since I did this project. However, I hope I can help you. I am using UST-20LX too. First of all, you can actually connect the laser to your computer through wired network. If im not wrong, you cant use internet too.

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2016-03-29**:
In order for you to connect to internet, you need to disconnect the wired network and connect to wireless. Thats a bit time consuming so I decided to do the above method. Hokuyo UST-20LX static IP is 192.168.0.10 while my WiFi connection is 192.168.0.10x. Therefore it clashes.

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2016-03-29**:
Thats why I need to create a new static ip of 192.168.0.15, leaving aside the wifi connection of 192.168.0.10x. May I know your internet connection IP?

**Comment by [SQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/26404/sq/) on 2016-03-29**:
Hi thanks for replying! My IP address is 192.168.0.100 for WiFi and 192.168.0.15 for the UST

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2016-03-29**:
If you follow this:
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
address 192.168.0.15
netmask 255.255.255.0

there should be no problem.

After setting this network interface, you need to type *sudo ifup eth0:0* to use laser and *sudo ifdown eth0:0* to use WiFi.

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2016-03-29**:
Or is it that you are facing other errors?

**Comment by [SQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/26404/sq/) on 2016-03-30**:
Sorry i tried ur method and i got this: Cannot find device "eth0:0" Failed to bring up eth0:0. i realised my eth port is eth3 so i changed it accordingly and i still get the same results

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2016-03-30**:
Can you type ***sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces*** and verify the interface? Are you still able to connect to WiFi?

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2016-03-30**:
If you check and everything is identical to mine, try:
***sudo ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.0.15 up***

this will disable your internet connection. Try connecting to hokuyo now.

To enable internet:
***sudo ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.0.15 down***

**Comment by [SQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/26404/sq/) on 2016-03-30**:
ok my project supervisor did something similar to that and it solved the problem. Thank u so much for your help!

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2016-03-30**:
Thats great. Wish you all the best!

**Comment by [AutoCar](https://answers.ros.org/users/35903/autocar/) on 2018-07-20**:
Does  you method enable us to use laser and WIFI at the same time? Sounds like it does not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What is the IP address range for your Wifi network?

I suspect you have overlapping IP address ranges for your Hokuyo and your Wifi network.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2015-06-17**:
Hi there! I checked my Wifi's connection information and the IPv4 is 192.168.0.111. My Hokuyo's IP is 192.168.0.10.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-06-17**:
Yes, your IP address ranges overlap (both are 192.168.0.X). If you can, try changing the IP address of your Hokuyo and the IP of the eth0:0 interface that you use to connect to it. Maybe use 192.168.7.10 and 192.168.7.15 ?

**Comment by [psprox96](https://answers.ros.org/users/22776/psprox96/) on 2015-06-17**:
Wow i can try that! Thanks for your help!

**Comment by [malgudi](https://answers.ros.org/users/29206/malgudi/) on 2018-06-19**:
Hi psprox96. i am also facing same problem. My wifi address is 172.16.x.x and eth0 address is 192.168.x.x but its not working. Could you tell me where am I going wrong?